# monit status does not reflect its own reality

Tags: ruby-on-rails, status, monit

I am using monit to monitor a couple of custom rails daemons.  They boot slowly on a raspberry pi (no surprise there).  But the monit summary command endlessly alternates between `waiting` and `execution failed` even though the log says the daemons are running, as does the alert email.  The daemons are not continuously restarting.

My monit config file looks like

```
check process setpoint_manager with pidfile /opt/thermyos.com/server/current/tmp/pids/setpoint_manager.pid every 2 cycles
  start program = "/etc/init.d/setpoint_manager start" as uid thermyos and gid thermyos
  stop program  = "/etc/init.d/setpoint_manager stop"
  if 5 restarts within 5 cycles then timeout
```

The monit daemon cycle time is 60 seconds.  The log file shows

```
[EDT Aug 30 17:38:35] info     : 'setpoint_manager' process is running with pid 2984
```

And the monit email says

```
Exists Service setpoint_manager 

Date:        Fri, 30 Aug 2013 17:38:35
Action:      alert
Host:        thermdev
Description: process is running with pid 2984
```

I have verified that the pid files and `ps ax` match.  If I restart the daemons via monit, the status becomes correct.

Why doesn't monit status ever self-correct?

Answer (score 1):

I contacted the excellent support folks at M/Monit who explained that this was a known bug in monit 5.4 that was fixed in 5.5.  Since the 2013-07-26-wheezy-raspbian release apt-get only provides 5.4, I downloaded and built monit 5.6 and everything works great.  Problem solved.

In order to build on the Raspberry Pi without loading more stuff and while keeping the same configuration, I used the following config line:

```
./configure --without-pam --sysconfdir=/etc/monit
```